# "set as atlas feature for atlas" does not appear in QGIS

Tags: atlas

I would like to display the atlas as I select a feature on the map, but this option "set as atlas feature for atlas" does not appear for me when I click on the feature.
I imagine it should appear like this:

[image]

I don't know if I need to enable any extra settings.
My version of QGIS is: Windows 3.28.12-Firenze